# ArgumentException on setting DefaultStyleKey in custom control deriving from user control - Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have created user control **MyUserControl**. Now I want to create custom control **MyCustomControl** that derives from **MyUserControl**. MyCustomControl.cs code is following:

```
public class MyCustomControl : MyUserControl
    {
        public MyCustomControl()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyCustomControl);
        }
    }
```

I have Themes/Generic.xaml file with the style

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyCustomControl">
 ...
</Style>
```

Instantiating **MyCustomControl** at runtime I get **ArgumentException** executing the line

```
this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyCustomControl);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a type that derives from `UserControl` to `DefaultStyleKey` is explicitly disallowed by throwing a `ArgumentException` (why an ArgumentException and why no explanitory message is included only the SL team know).

A `UserControl` cannot be templated receiving instead its own associated Xaml.  Thats the whole point of `UserControl`.  You need to convert `MyUserControl` into a templatable control was well if you wish to inherit off it in manner you are attempting.

Comment: I see. Thanks! Is it possible to create CustomControl1 with it's default style and then create CustomControl2 deriving from CustomControl1 with CustomControl2 also having it's own default style? Initially I tried this scenario, but System.Exception occured at runtime